# VSCode - Remote C++ debugging

Tags: gdb, visual-studio-code

So, I have been trying for days to set up vscode to use the integrated debugger against a remote RPi (Compute Module). I have not had any luck so far.

My `launch.json`

```
{
        "name": "1w-Remote(2)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/examples/onewire/onewire",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb-arm-7.12",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "launchCompleteCommand": "None",
        "externalConsole": true,
        "linux": {
          "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "osx": {
          "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "windows": {
          "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "logging": {
            "engineLogging": true,
            "trace": true,
            "exceptions": true,
            "traceResponse": true
        },
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "text": "set mi-async off"
            },
            {
                "text": "target remote 10.106.0.157:8081"
            }
        ]
}
```

It seems like, once I fix one issue, a new one rises up. Is there anyone that can enlighten me on their process to set it up?

Comment: have you tried this https://medium.com/@spe_/debugging-c-c-programs-remotely-using-visual-studio-code-and-gdbserver-559d3434fb78?